# Is it joins again in ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Here's the problem:

List the title, authors first and last names and year to date sales for books whose authors have addresses in California and Utah.

the desc tables:

```
SQL> desc authors
 Name
 --------------------------
 AUTHOR_ID
 AUTHOR_LNAME
 AUTHOR_FNAME
 PHONE
 ADDRESS
 CITY
 STATE
 ZIP

SQL> desc title_authors
 Name
 --------------------------
 AUTHOR_ID
 TITLE_ID
 AUTHOR_ORD
 ROYALTY_SHARE

SQL> desc titles
 Name
 --------------------------
 TITLE_ID
 TITLE
 TYPE
 PUBLISHER_ID
 PRICE
 ADVANCE
 YTD_SALES
 CONTRACT
 NOTES
 PUBLICATION_DATE
```

Here's what Ive tried w/ results......

```
SQL> SELECT  AUTHORS.AUTHOR_FNAME, AUTHOR_LNAME, TITLES.TITLE, TITLES.YTD_SALES
  2  FROM AUTHORS
  3  JOIN TITLE_AUTHORS ON AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID = TITLE_AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID
  4  JOIN TITLES ON TITLE_AUTHORS.TITLE_ID = TITLES.TITLE_ID
  5  WHERE STATE = 'CA'
  6  OR STATE = 'UT';

AUTHOR_FNAME         AUTHOR_LNAME                             TITLE                                  YTD_SALES
-------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
Marjorie             GreeN                                    The Busy Executive's Database Guide         4095
Marjorie             GreeN                                    You Can Combat Computer Stress!            18722
Dick                 StrAight                                 Straight Talk About Computers               4095
```

Note 3 full results returned.
Next trial, which Ive tried various versions of, returns 3 full records, but the entire authors list:

```
AUTHOR_FNAME         AUTHOR_LNAME TITLE                                     YTD_SALES
-------------------- ------------ ---------------------------------------- ----------
Marjorie             GreeN        The Busy Executive's Database Guide            4095
Marjorie             GreeN        You Can Combat Computer Stress!               18722
Dick                 StrAight     Straight Talk About Computers                  4095
Albert               Ringer
Ann                  Dull
JOHNSON              White
Chastity             Locksley
Anne                 RINGER
Stearns              MacFeatHer
Anne                 RINGER
Michael              O'Leary
Stearns              MacFeatHer
Livia                Karsen
Abraham              BeNNet
Albert               Ringer
Michael              O'Leary
Sheryl               Hunter
Cheryl               Carson
Chastity             Locksley
```

What is this? Is it blocked somehow? I can see the entire tables individually.
Any one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT  AUTHORS.AUTHOR_FNAME, AUTHOR_LNAME, TITLES.TITLE, TITLES.YTD_SALES
  FROM AUTHORS
  INNER JOIN TITLE_AUTHORS ON AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID = TITLE_AUTHORS.AUTHOR_ID
  INNER  JOIN TITLES ON TITLE_AUTHORS.TITLE_ID = TITLES.TITLE_ID
  WHERE STATE = 'CA' OR STATE = 'UT';
```

Comment: @ Tech Mahesh  That gives the first result, just 3 full records

Comment: @ Tech Mahesh  no, see my 2nd code box, above, thats what I keep getting.

Comment: add one more condition in where as like below, AND TITLES.TITLE IS NOT NULL

Comment: NONE of the title are null in the table.